# SQL query order date by ASC, but past entries on end?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm currently working on an artist website containing an agenda for gigs. I want it to list the first upcoming gigs on the beginning (asc), and list the past gigs after the upcoming gigs. My current solution is two different queries, one calling upcoming and one past events, but I think it's neater to figure out a way to merge them. Does anybody know if this is possible, and how?

This is how I begin;

```
SELECT * 
FROM agenda 
INNER JOIN organizer ON agenda.agenda_organizer=organizer.organizer_id
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM agenda 
INNER JOIN organizer ON agenda.agenda_organizer=organizer.organizer_id
ORDER BY
CASE WHEN yourDateColumn > NOW() THEN 1
     WHEN yourDateColumn < NOW() THEN 2
END ASC,
yourDateColumn
```

Comment: You should also add `yourDateColumn` to the 'ORDER BY` clause; otherwise, you could just get an unordered set of upcoming, with an unordered set of past events.

Comment: I'm very sorry for the delayed answer, had some health problems. Back in business though. Thank you for pointing me into the right direction!!

Comment: By the way, I assume this also orders the 'past' events ASC. Is there a way to order the past events DESC, so that the most recent past events are listed first in the past events part?

Comment: Ordering the same column in two different directions is not possible, I'm afraid. Neither `CASE WHEN...` nor self-joining nor `UNION` helps here, you'll have to do it on application layer.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a [UNION](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp), then you can do the two statements neatly - and because each [ORDER BY](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp) is simply on the date field, you know it will use the [index](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-indexes.htm) to keep your query fast:

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM agenda 
    INNER JOIN organizer ON agenda.agenda_organizer=organizer.organizer_id
    WHERE yourDateColumn > NOW()
    ORDER BY yourDateColumn ASC
UNION ALL
    SELECT * 
    FROM agenda 
    INNER JOIN organizer ON agenda.agenda_organizer=organizer.organizer_id
    WHERE yourDateColumn < NOW()
    ORDER BY yourDateColumn DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
 (SELECT * FROM agenda WHERE yourDateColumn > NOW() ORDER BY yourDateColumn ASC) future

UNION ALL

SELECT * 
FROM
 (SELECT * FROM agenda WHERE yourDateColumn < NOW() ORDER BY yourDateColumn DESC) past
```

This should select first upcoming event ASC and then past event DESC

Answer (score 0):

Ordering the same column in two directions is possible with the trick:

```
SELECT yourDateColumn,IF(yourDateColumn)<NOW(),DATEDIFF(yourDateColumn),NOW()) * -1000000000,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(CONVERT_TZ(e.startDate,e.timeZone,'Europe/Paris'), '%Y-%m-%d'))) AS diff FROM yourTable ORDER BY DIFF ASC;
```

The key here is multiplying by big enough negative number so date is sorted eventually by upcoming ASC then past DESC.